# Prediction intervals for forecasts using spectral analysis

Tags: forecasting, bootstrap, prediction-interval, spectral-analysis

I have circadian data which typically have a period of around 24 hours so using spectral analysis seems appropriate. I've used spectrum resampling which is quite robust to changes in period which suits my needs. This bootstraps from the smoothed periodogram to obtain an estimate of the most significant peaks. From this I've performed a least squares fit of the data using these frequencies and given a forecast.

Now, I want to calculate prediction intervals on the forecasts. Is there any technique specific to this example?

I do have confidence intervals of all significant frequencies but using these to plot prediction intervals gives a somewhat "wobbly" PIs.

I was also thinking I could bootstrap the data used to calculate the Fourier coefficients, but this would also give wobbly PIs.

Failing this, would a parametric PI using RMSE or similar be sufficient/appropriate?

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Black is the data.
Green is the model.
Red is the upper PI and blue is the lower PI.

As you can see, the results are far from satisfactory.

I'm not sure this counts as a "short" example. The code I've written is generalised for many "windows" of data so I've had to break my code a bit to run for this one window.

```
Period = c(4.266605, 19.53994, 8.097199, 3.48469, 2.880046)
Lower = c(4.237288, 7.042254, 6.944444, 3.436426, 2.832861)
Upper = c(4.310345, 21.73913, 20.833333, 3.484321, 2.906977)  
data <- c(27.4, 14.1, 5.72, 2.47, 14.22, 10.32, 0.37, 2.13, 8.73, 7.47, 
      7.27, 5, 3.47, 2.22, 9.85, 3.1, 3.12, 20.05, 12.95, 4.38, 0.43, 
      5.57, 19.72, 12.38, 11.13, 20.88, 12.42, 0.33, 2.08, 0.18, 2.2, 
      10.4, 0.43, 0.78, 5.25, 10.08, 0.48, 7.22, 12.25, 24.27, 5.7, 
      1.37, 9.95, 13.63, 10.3, 1.98, 15.58, 5.23)


forecast<- matrix(NA, nrow=72, ncol=3)
xvals <- seq(1:72)



si <- matrix(NA, nrow=48, ncol=5)
co <- matrix(NA, nrow=48, ncol=5)

for(j in 1:5)
  for(k in 1:48){


    si[k, j] <- cos(2*pi*xvals[k]/Period[j])
    co[k, j] <- sin(2*pi*xvals[k]/Period[j])
  }

summ <- cbind(si,co)
#dt <- detrend(i)
FC <- solve(t(summ)%*%summ)%*%t(summ)%*%data

#################################################################################    

upp_co <- matrix(NA, nrow=24, ncol=5)
upp_si <- matrix(NA, nrow=24, ncol=5)
low_co <- matrix(NA, nrow=24, ncol=5)
low_si <- matrix(NA, nrow=24, ncol=5)
fit_co <- matrix(NA, nrow=72, ncol=5)
fit_si <- matrix(NA, nrow=72, ncol=5)

for(j in 1:5)
  for(k in 1:72){


fit_co[k, j] <- cos(2*pi*xvals[k]/Period[j])
fit_si[k, j] <- sin(2*pi*xvals[k]/Period[j])

}

  for(j in 1:5)
  for(k in 1:24){

    upp_co[k, j] <- cos(2*pi*xvals[k]/Upper[j])
    upp_si[k, j] <- sin(2*pi*xvals[k]/Upper[j])
    low_co[k, j] <- cos(2*pi*xvals[k]/Lower[j])
    low_si[k, j] <- sin(2*pi*xvals[k]/Lower[j])

  }

upp_sum <- cbind(upp_co,upp_si)
low_sum <- cbind(low_co,low_si)
fit_sum <- cbind(fit_co,fit_si)


forecast[1:72,1] <- fit_sum%*%FC
forecast[49:72,2] <- upp_sum%*%FC
forecast[49:72,3] <- low_sum%*%FC

undetrend <- function(data, fore){

 trend <- time(data)

 reg <- lm(data ~ trend, na.action=NULL)
 for(i in 1:72){
   detr <- fore + reg$coe[1] + reg$coe[2]*i
   return(detr)
 }
}

plot(data, type="l", xlim=c(0,72))
lines(undetrend(data,forecast[,1]), col="forestgreen")
lines(undetrend(data,forecast[,2]), col="red")
lines(undetrend(data,forecast[,3]), col="blue")
```

Comment: I took the liberty of changing your tags from [tag:confidence-interval] (which refers to an interval for an *unobservable* quantity) to [tag:prediction-interval] (which refers to an interval for a *not yet observed future realization*). It's a small but not completely irrelevant difference.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "wobbly" PIs?

Comment: I stand corrected about the wrongly worded confidence intervals, thank you for that.

Comment: And since it was my first post, I was unable to add a picture of what I meant but wobbly is certainly ambiguous. My idea of using the lower and upper 2.5% of bootstrapped period estimations produced intervals that overlapped each other and did not envelop the forecast as expected. Sometimes the "upper" PI would be below the "lower" PI for example. I fear that without a picture I won't be able explain this properly.

Comment: Can you upload your picture elsewhere and link to it from here? Or even better, provide a minimal reproducible example, ideally in R?

Comment: Just enough reputation to add a graph, I hope this clears it up. I've added an example too which runs through the least squares fit and produces the graph.

Comment: I think I don't understand, starting with the `undetrend` function. You fit a linear slope to your data, and then you add the forecast from this simple model to your forecast. So you take *both* your spectral forecast *and* a linear trend model and *add* them together. Do you really want to do this?

Comment: After doing a bit more reading, it would seem that the fit is missing a constant term. The code I've written is based on theory from the MATLAB package I use to perform the spectrum resampling. However, MATLAB detrends the data before analysing. What is the appropriate way to add a constant term? Is there a cleaner way to perform the fit in general?